# Are uninitialized references zero-initialized and uninitialized scalars default-initialized?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer

Are the following statements correct?

- An uninitialized reference is considered zero-initialized.
- An uninitialized scalar is considered default-initialized.
- Any other uninitialized entity is not considered zero-initialized nor default-initialized.

They are based on [[dcl.init.general/6]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#general-6) (bold emphasis mine):

> To *zero-initialize* an object or reference of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a scalar type, the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal `0` (zero) to `T`;
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, its padding bits are initialized to zero bits and each non-static data member, each non-virtual base class subobject, and, if the object is not a base class subobject, each virtual base class subobject is zero-initialized;
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, its padding bits are initialized to zero bits and the object's first non-static named data member is zero-initialized;
> - if `T` is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
> - if `T` is a reference type, **no initialization** is performed.

and on [[dcl.init.general/7]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#general-7) (bold emphasis mine):

> To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - If `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one for the *initializer* `()` is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]). The constructor thus selected is called, with an empty argument list, to initialize the object.
> - If `T` is an array type, each element is default-initialized.
> - Otherwise, **no initialization** is performed.

Comment: out of curiosity, do you have an example of an uninitialized reference? I thought thats not possible

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: maybe, in the process of initialization of `static`/`global` variables. (zero initialization is performed before dynamic initialization IIRC).

Comment: @Jarod42 oh right, or as member of a class when it isnt the first member

Comment: @Jarod42 its impossible to reassign a reference.

Comment: I misread the question of 463035818_is_not_a_number, as when  zero-initialize a reference happens.

Comment: @Kaihaku: I didn't mean to reassign a reference, but step to initialize a global (which is or have a reference).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization might help.

Comment: @Jarod42 what I mean by that is that its impossible to have a global reference like that. And why would it be meaninglessly zeroed out? I'm not aware of this functionality being mandated by this standard. The closest thing to it is when a new process is created, a modern operating system will zero out any memory to avoid leakage of data from an old page across processes. Which has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: @Jarod42 you are confusing "static initialization" and "zero initialization"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the standard **also** says that if a reference is not initialized, the program is ill-formed. So the fact that zero-init of a reference is defined as "nothing happens" is kinda moot, because it would be ill-formed anyway.

Comment: Consider struct foo_t { int a; int& b; }, it will have its default constructor deleted and can't be initialized. Even providing a constructor that does nothing will not compile, the reference member must be initialized. There should be no "legal" way to zero initialize a reference.

Comment: I have another question: Has an entity that has been *vacuously* initialised, been initialised at all?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Better phrased then I did, but that's what I meant

Comment: @eerorika since vacuous initialization is defined as "A variable is said to
have vacuous initialization if it is default-initialized and [...]" then yes, because it must have been default-initialized, which means it's been initialized.

Comment: @dfrib, no, scalar types can also have vacuous init. You are misreading it. "if it is default-initialized, and *if** it is of class type or [...] array] thereof" (emphasis mine). For non-class and non-array-of-class-types the only necessary precondition is the first part, "if it is default-initialized".

Comment: @JonathanWakely But if default-initaialisation is vacuous, then it means that *"no initialisation has been performed"*. Is there no contradiction between "is initialised" and "initialisation has not been performed"?

Comment: @eerorika not all default-initialization is vacuous. Default init of a non-trivial class type is non-vacuous, it uses a constructor. "Is default-initialized" has a specific meaning, clearly defined, and even for a particular type T if it means "the bytes of the object representation are not initialized" then it has still been _default-initialized_.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I see, thanks.

Comment: @JonathanWakely `not all default-initialization is vacuous` But some default initialisation is vacuous. I'm specifically asking about default initialisation that is vacuous. `"Is default-initialized" has a specific meaning` I'm specifically asking about "Is **initialised**".

Comment: @eerorika and the point of "vacuous initialization" is that such a type can still be considered "initialized" even if that initialization is entirely vacuous, i.e. doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JonathanWakely To continue, when the standard says, **shall be initialized**, is vacuous initialisation sufficient to satisfy it?

Comment: I assume you mean [dcl.constexpr] p10, and no, vacuous initialization is not sufficient there (as shown non-normatively by the example). I think the wording is poor though, it should be more precise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are the following statements correct?

No, you are flipping the logical connections on their heads.

The definitions of "zero-initialization" and "default-initialization" specify what it means if something else in the standard says "the object is zero-initialized". When the standard says that, you use the definition of zero-initialization to see what it means. For a reference, it means no initialization is done. So a zero-initialized reference is uninitialized (and therefore ill-formed).

That does not imply the inverse though. An uninitialized reference is not zero-initialized. This is a fallacy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent

A reference is zero-initialized *when the standard says zero-initialization is performed*.

Comment: Thanks. If I may require your expertise again, I have opened a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69221161/2326961) that did not get any answer so far.

Answer (score 4):

(Several questions in the same questions: I will answer one)

> Is the following statement correct?
>
> - An uninitialized reference is considered zero-initialized.

No. There is no such thing as an uninitialized reference, as it would need to refer to a variable or object, as opposed to a (reference type) parameter or a (reference type) return type, in which context initialization do not apply; as per [[dcl.init.ref]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.ref#1) and [/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.ref#3):

> /1 A variable whose declared type is “reference to T” ([dcl.ref])
> **shall be initialized.**
>
> /3 The initializer can be omitted for a reference only in a parameter
> declaration ([dcl.fct]), in the declaration of a function return type,
> in the declaration of a class member within its class definition
> ([class.mem]), and where the extern specifier is explicitly used.

Regarding the quoted [[dcl.init.general]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.general#6):

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - [...]
> - [...] if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

it refers to the cases where other parts of the standard governs that zero-initialization *applies* (and what is the *effect* of it for different entities); for initialization of a reference, particularly consider static initialization, as governed per [[basic.start.static]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#2):

> [...] If constant initialization is not performed, **a variable with static storage duration** ([basic.stc.static]) or thread storage duration ([basic.stc.thread]) **is zero-initialized** ([dcl.init]). Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; **all other initialization is dynamic initialization.** All static initialization strongly happens before ([intro.races]) any dynamic initialization.

Such that static initialization of a reference type variable (which is not constant-initialized) will pertain solely of dynamic initialization, as the effect of the zero initialization of first step of static initialization is no initialization.

Answer (score 3):

> An uninitialized reference is considered zero-initialized.

It could be if the uninitialised reference has been zero-initialised. That said, there is no observable difference between an uninitialised reference that has been zero-initialised and an uninitialised reference that hasn't been zero-initialised.

> An uninitialized scalar is considered default-initialized.

It could be if the uninitialised scalar has been default-initialised. That said, there is no observable difference between an uninitialised scalar that has been default-initialised and an uninitialised scalar that hasn't been default-initialised.

> Any other uninitialized entity is not considered zero-initialized nor default-initialized.

An entity is considered to be zero-initialised after it has been zero-initialised and it's considered to be default-initialised after it has been default initialised.