# Why is the concept of vacuous initialization necessary?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, object-lifetime

The concept of *vacuous initialization* is introduced and used at [[basic.life/1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic#life-1), and it does not seem to be used anywhere else in the C++ standard:

> The *lifetime* of an object or reference is a runtime property of the object or reference. A variable is said to have *vacuous initialization* if it is default-initialized and, if it is of class type or a (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof, that class type has a trivial default constructor. The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
> - its initialization (if any) is complete (including vacuous initialization) ([dcl.init]),

Since vacuous initialization is a subset of default initialization, it is **initialization** for class and array types, and **no initialization** for scalar types (cf. [[dcl.init.general/7]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#general-7)), and therefore both cases are covered by the phrase ‘initialization (if any)’.

So why is the concept of vacuous initialization necessary?

The quote seems equivalent to this amended version:

> The *lifetime* of an object or reference is a runtime property of the object or reference. The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
> - its initialization (if any) is complete ([dcl.init]),

Comment: See also [What problem does it solve that for not non-vacuous initialization, lifetime begins before initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164295/what-problem-does-it-solve-that-for-not-non-vacuous-initialization-lifetime-beg)

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks but that question is obsolete, the clause in question has been updated in the C++17 standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current draft standard, quoted by the OP, has reached its state via [CWG issue 2256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1358r0.html#2256) (*2256. Lifetime of trivially-destructible objects*) and [P1787R6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html) (*P1787R6: Declarations and where to find them*), after which, if any, the *term* (rather than "the concept") can be used to collective refer to cases where "initialization" will not suffice.

At the very least, it is referred to from [[stmt.dcl]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.dcl#3):

> Upon each transfer of control (including sequential execution of statements) within a function from point P to point Q, all variables that are active at P and not at Q are destroyed in the reverse order of their construction. Then, all variables that are active at Q but not at P are initialized in declaration order; **unless all such variables have vacuous initialization** ([basic.life]), the transfer of control shall not be a jump. [...]

Simply "initialization" does naturally not suffice here, as variable could have non-vacuous initialization such that a jump between point `P` to point `Q` would violate the restriction of [stmt.dcl]/3.

If we were to amend [basic.life/1] as proposed, the term would no longer be defined, and e.g. [stmt.dcl]/3 would need to explicitly write out the full initialization contexts for where a jump (under the P->Q restrictions) is allowed.

Comment: Thanks, I had not noticed that the definition was used in [\[stmt.dcl\]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.dcl#3) (and only there).

Comment: But I am not convinced that a definition used once in the whole standard justifies a definition. Is ‘vacuous initialization’ used by developers or at least compiler developers or language designers?

Comment: @Maggyero My own experience as a non-expert language lawyer is that subtle lifetime topics are _hard_, and you typically see defect reports on the topic from the well-renowned LL experts such as R. Smith. Given that vacuous init. has undergone a few changes over the years, it could be that one could likewise remove the _term_ and move the initialization context description to [stmt.dcl]/3. But whilst this may seem like an editorial ("text shuffling") change, it would remove the term entirely, which may surprise compiler implementors and similar, the few ones that would actually use this term.